# In an abelian category, show that $f(A) = f(B)$ implies $A \subseteq ((A+B) \cap \text{Ker} f) + B$.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, diagram-chasing

Title: In an abelian category, show that $f(A) = f(B)$ implies $A \subseteq ((A+B) \cap \text{Ker} f) + B$.

I'm trying to show this result with as little machinery as possible. This includes not using any diagram lemmas (as far as it is possible) or embedding theorems. This means basically only using universal properties or (simple) facts about subobjects, some of which will be outlined below.

Here $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism, $A$ and $B$ are subobjects of $X$ (equivalence classes of monos with codomain $X$).

$f(A)$ is defined to be the image of the inclusion of $A$ into $X$ followed by $f$.

Sums (unions) and intersections of subobjects are defined as joins and meets in the poset of subobjects. To actually construct these, we can set

$$ A + B = \text{Im}(A \oplus B \to X ) $$

where the maps from $A$ and $B$ to $X$ are just the subobject inclusions.

The intersection can be constructed as the pullback of the diagram consisting of the inclusions of $A$ and $B$ in $X$.

Some extra information that might be useful:

For a morphism $f : X \to Y$ and a subobject $B \subseteq Y$, we can define the preimage $f^{-1}(B)$ to be the largest subobject $P$ of $X$ satisfying $f(P) \subseteq B$, i.e. a subobject $P$ such that $A \subseteq P \iff f(A) \subseteq B$. The preimage can be constructed by taking the pullback of the diagram consisting of f and the inclusion of $B$ into $Y$.

Here are some results I already know (they can be proved elementarily):

$f$ mono $\implies f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$

$f$ epi (or even just $B \subseteq \text{Im} f$) $\implies f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$

$f(A_1 + A_2) = f(A_1) + f(A_2)$

$f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_1) = f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2)$

Some motivation: this (title) result is supposed to facilitate a diagram chasing technique where one chases subobjects. The one thing I need to make things work out nicely is a notion of "subtraction" of subobjects. More precisely, in a situation where $f(A) = f(B)$, I'd like there to be a subobject, call it $A -_f B$, with is supposed to be a "difference with respect to $f$", which satisfies $f(A -_f B) = 0$ and $A \subseteq (A -_f B) + B$ (equality in the second condition is too much to ask for). In module categories one can check that $(A + B) \cap \text{Ker} f$ does the job, and the title question is just checking that the second condition for this choice of "difference" holds in abelian categories.

One more thing: I am aware of "generalized elements" from Mac Lane's book, but as far as I am aware his "difference" of elements doesn't have a corresponding "$(a - b) + b = a$" property.

This is my first Math StackExchange question, so I apologize for any formatting mistakes or things that may be unclear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what restrictions exactly you want to work with, so as a possible outline: consider $V$ as the pullback of $f |_A : A \to f(A) = f(B)$ and $f |_B : B \to f(B)$, with maps $a : V \to A$ and $b : V \to B$.  Then $a-b$ factors through $(A+B) \cap \ker(f)$, so $a$ factors through $((A + B) \cap \ker(f)) + B$.  And since $a$ is an epimorphism (as a pullback of an epimorphism), that implies the desired result.

Comment: Just tried it out, works perfectly! And yeah, this really doesn't use anything other than that epis are preserved under pullbacks in abelian categories, which is fine to assume. How did you get the idea to take the pullback V?

Comment: At the last sentence, it also uses the fact that epimorphisms are left-orthogonal to monomorphisms (i.e. if you have a commutative square where the left morphism is epi and the right morphism is mono, there exists a unique diagonal morphism (bottom left to top right) making two commutative triangles).

Comment: Anyway, the idea basically started with the "generalized elements" type of argument, with a bit of unfolding after that.  The version of generalized elements I prefer is to work with a "test object" $U$ and consider the morphisms from $U$ to the objects in the diagram (so it relates to the point of view involving Yoneda's lemma).  The key fact you use about epimorphisms in this method is: a morphism $f : A \to B$ is epi if and only if for each test object $U$ and generalized element $b \in B(U) := \operatorname{Hom}(U, B)$...

Comment: there exists an epimorphism $\pi : V \to U$ and generalized element $a \in A(V)$ such that $\pi^* b = f(a)$ where $\pi^* b$ is suggestive notation for $b \circ \pi \in B(V)$ and $f(a)$ is suggestive notation for $f \circ a \in B(V)$.

Comment: So, the argument goes: take a test object $U$ and a generalized element $a \in A(U)$.  Then since $f(a)$ factors through $f(A)$ and $f(A) = f(B)$, there exists an epi $\pi : V \to U$ and $b \in B(V)$ such that $f(b) = f(\pi^* a)$.  Then $\pi^* a-b$ factors through $(A+B)\cap \ker(f)$, so $\pi^* a$ factors through $((A+B)\cap \ker(f)) + B$.  Since $\pi$ is epi, that implies $a$ factors through $((A+B)\cap \ker(f)) + B$ also.  Since this is true for all $U, a$, we must have $A \subseteq ((A+B)\cap \ker(f)) + B$.

Comment: In fact, I tend to think about the test object method as being very much like how you would do the proofs in the category of sheaves of abelian groups on a topological space.  So where the method has a test object $U$, I think of the special case $\mathbb{Z}_U$ for some open set $U$.  And where the method passes to an epimorphic cover $\pi:V\to U$, I think of the special case of  passing from $U$ to an open cover $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \}$ of $U$, where $\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}_{V_i} \to \mathbb{Z}_U$ is then an epimorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! When filling in the details of the proof, it surprised me how similar the overarching reasoning is (modulo technicalities) to the proof in R-Mod, once we use the test objects as "platforms" allowing you to use elements (by viewing them as morphisms from the test object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the pullback of $f |_A : A \to f(A) = f(B)$ and $f |_B : B \to f(B)$, with projections $a : V \to A$ and $b : V \to B$.  Then $a - b$ factors through $(A + B) \cap \ker(f)$, so $a$ factors through $((A+B) \cap \ker(f)) + B$.  However, since $a$ is an epimorphism (as a pullback of an epimorphism), that implies the desired result.